# Dynamic html with angular bindings not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind

I have a simple javascript code that dynamically adds HTML content to a div tag.

```
function addData(id,title,title_data){

  var htmlcode='';

  htmlcode+=`<h1> Title: `+title+` </h1> <div ng-app="">
              <input ng-model="model`+title+id`" ng-init="model`+title+id+'='+\'`+title_data+`\'`"    >`+


`<p ng-bind="model`+title+id`"> </p>`;



   return htmlcode;
}
```

Then i simply use it like this:

```
$('#someDiv').html(addData(1,'Some Title','Some title data'));
```

The html works well and displays the desired dynamic content. But the angular bindings didn't work. The copy pasted version of the rendered html from web browser works well including the bindings but the dynamic one does not. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: I think that might because the bindings have already been created for the existing entities during page load. And you are trying to add new bindings later on in your code.

Comment: Firstly, `$('#someDiv')` is jQuery code, not angular;  trying to use angular in this way is highly irregular, and not recommended.  This seems to indicate that perhaps your overall app design isn't fully embracing angular.  If you are able to re-factor your app to remove jQuery and *still* find that you need HTML strings like this (rather than angular templates or simillar), then, **and only then**, should you look at how to compile dynamic expressions.

Comment: Beyond my last comment, the actual angular code you are using here is a *very old syntax*, for angular version 1.2, which is more than 3 years old.  Newer releases of angular **will not work when `ng-app===""`.**

Comment: Any code that modifies DOM should be implemented as directive. You mixed JQuery DOM manipulation with angular. The angular data binding will not work here until you tell angularjs to compile and re run digest cycle.

Comment: The binding also depends on how the data is manipulated in angular. Can you show how the title object is being updated? If it loses reference then it will not update.

Comment: @Claies Thanks for the insight. I'm actually only using angular for  the binding through html attribubute and skipping the scripting side as possible. Most of my modules use jquery and i only use angular to lessen my jquery scripting side.

Comment: That is, unfortunately, a very terrible idea and not how angular was intended to be implemented.  Due to how angular manages the DOM, this pattern is a recipe for frustration.

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara Hi thank you for your answer. What do you mean by compile and rerun digest cycle? Is it similar to document.ready of jquery?

Comment: @Claies The problem is I'm just adding a module in an already existing website mostly done in jquery. I'm actually new to angular js and was amazed by the bindings feature. Do you recommend that i just use pure angular js in that particular module even in other modules jquery is present?

Comment: If you plan on using angular at all, you should try to eliminate jquery.  It isn't as hard as it sounds, and if you find something you really think you need jquery for, it's likely that someone already wrote an angular replacement.

Comment: @Ruben compilation step compiles any angularjs directive markups into HTML markup. Simply put, browser does not understand markup like `ng-model` etc. Normally angularjs runs initial compilation after it finished loading. But sometimes developers add new directive markups when doing DOM manipulation after first compilation. To make newly-added directive markup works you need to let angularjs know that it needs to translate this into proper HTML markup. Digest cycle responsible for update model value for data binding between model and its view

Comment: the main problem here is that angular is initialized on page load;  adding an `ng-app` to the DOM after the page is finished loading doesn't tell angular that it should go looking for that element.  if you are insistent that this is the only way you can develop this app, you will be responsible for manually bootstrapping the app (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap), but this *generally* means you need to know a bit more about how the framework works, and after you spend time learning about it, you'll realize how much of a terrible idea this really is.

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara Thanks for the clarification! I didn't know angularjs works needs to compile first for directives to work. The weird thing is that it worked when i used php to echo the js script. https://imgur.com/a/5gsHf

Comment: Using PHP does work because when browser finishes loading your HTML and angularjs, all directive markups are there when angularjs does it compilation. So yes it works. I could not agree more with @Claies, it is terrible idea to use angularjs the way you use now.

Comment: @Claies Hi, since the only jquery im using for this module is $(#).html , theoretically i just need to use the angular equivalent for this to work.

Comment: you still misunderstand completely how AngularJs works.  Angular doesn't "Manipulate the DOM" the way that jQuery does.  Angular loads when it is bootstrapped, and creates watchers for all the angular bindings it finds, then responds to the watchers later.  If the content isn't present in the DOM at the time of page load, angular doesn't create a watcher, and therefore doesn't ever have anything to respond to.  You can't attach HTML into the DOM later with `ng-app` in it and expect it to work, since that is the bootstrap flag that angular is **only looking for on page load**.

Comment: I linked the documentation for manual bootstrapping, which is definitely something you can try, but it's not the optimal way to use the framework, and has many quirks when you start trying to bootstrap multiple modules, which end up being separate apps, with separate concerns, lack of communication, potential to change each other, etc.  I don't really know how many other ways to say it, **THIS ISN'T A GOOD IDEA.**

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `ng-app` name in the declared dynamic html code.